# Using regex to retrieve part of string using underscore with perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string of text like these:

```
20130312214255_HD7870Crossfire_Crysis3_1920x1080
20130312221402_HD7870Crossfire_SleepingDogs_1920x1080
20130313133415_HD7870CrossFire_Crysis3_5760x1080
```

What I want to return is:

```
Crysis3_1920x1080

SleepingDogs_1920x1080

Crysis3_5760x1080
```

I have very little experience with regex and could use some help.  Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  You are expected to make some effort first before posting here. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Answer (score 2):

A very short way, using a regex as requested:

```
perl -ple'($_)=/([^_]+_[^_]+$)/' file
```

or

```
perl -ple's/.*_(?=[^_]+_)//' file
```

(Doesn't assume there's only two segments to remove like some of the other answers do.)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/Crossfire_(.*)/)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the offset is always the same in your example, you can also use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) to do this:

```
perl -ple'$_=substr$_,31' file
```

Answer (score 1):

He didn't say it HAD to be a regex...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '20130312221402_HD7870Crossfire_SleepingDogs_1920x1080';
my ($datetime, $card, $game, $resolution) = split /_/, $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

For single string you could use:

```
my $str = "20130312214255_HD7870Crossfire_Crysis3_1920x1080";
$str =~ s/^(?:[^_]*_){2}//;
```

If it contains multiple strings, you can do something like:

```
my $str = <<'_STR_';
20130312214255_HD7870Crossfire_Crysis3_1920x1080
20130312221402_HD7870Crossfire_SleepingDogs_1920x1080
20130313133415_HD7870CrossFire_Crysis3_5760x1080
_STR_

my @result = $str =~ /^(?:[^_]*_){2}(\S+)/gm;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
perl -F_ -ape '$_=join "_",@F[-2,-1];' file
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your example try this pattern with regular expressions

```
[^_ ]*_[0-9]{4}[xX][0-9]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a="20130312214255_HD7870Crossfire_Crysis3_1920x1080";
if($a=~m/Crossfire_(.*)/){
    print $1;
}
```